# SignalR - Handling connected and disconnected users

Tags: c#, timer, websocket, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm using Signalr on my project, I'm displaying all online users in table,
when user change page the disconnected event is fired, then connected.

In my view it's not very clean because the user is deleted then added.
To close this problem I added an timer array, when user unload page , I add
a timer that will check after something like 5 seconds if this user still online (in my users array) , if not the view will notified that he is disconnected.
In the OnConnected event I will check if the timer exists in my timer array and will dispose it, however sometimes it's not working when I do refresh many times and the user is not deleted...

Thanks you for your help.

here my code example :

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConnectTimer> ConnectionTimers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConnectTimer>();


private class ConnectTimer : Timer
{
     public ConnectTimer(double interval) : base(interval) { }
     public object Id { get; set; }
}



 private void OnVisitorDisconnected(Visitor visitor, string connectionId)
    {
        visitor.ConnectionIds.RemoveWhere(cid => cid.Equals(connectionId));
        if (visitor.ConnectionIds.Any())
            return;

        Visitor removedVisitor;
        Visitors.TryRemove(visitor.Id.ToString(), out removedVisitor);

        /*********only after  timer tick ****/

        var timer = new ConnectTimer(DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT);
        timer.Elapsed += VisitorDisconnected_Tick;
        timer.Id = visitor.Id.ToString();
        timer.Enabled = true;

        ConnectionTimers[visitor.Id.ToString()] = timer;


        /********************************/

    }


 public void VisitorDisconnected_Tick(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var timer  = (ConnectTimer)source;
        var visitorId = timer.Id.ToString();

        var visitor = Visitors.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Key == visitorId);
        if (visitor.Value != null)
        {
            ConnectTimer removedTimer;
            ConnectionTimers.TryRemove(visitor.Id.ToString(), out removedTimer);
            if (removedTimer != null)
            {
                removedTimer.Enabled = false;
                removedTimer.Dispose();
            }
            return;
        }


        var ids = Agents.Values.Select(c => c.ConnectionIds).SelectMany(agentConnections => agentConnections).ToList();
        Clients.Clients(ids).visitorDisconnected(visitorId);
    }
```

Comment: You are not handling if this fails        Visitor removedVisitor;
        Visitors.TryRemove(visitor.Id.ToString(), out removedVisitor);

Comment: check this example https://github.com/anik123/Chat-With-Angularjs-Signalr-Web-Api---Sql-server here i manage online user.